# Various file/data formats supported in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I came across the below code somewhere.

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

Looks like `com.databricks.spark.csv` is file format supported by *Databricks*.
I want to know what all file/data formats are supported natively by *Apache-Spark* (prior to 2.0.0)

Comment: See here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-sources

Answer (score 2):

Spark supports all the formats supported by Hadoop eco system. 
Below are the formats works well with spark.

1.textfile

2.sequencefile

3.json

4.avro (lightweight and fast serialization/deserialization)

5.parquet(column oriented and gives better compression ratio)